# Return a generic IList filtered by a Where or Select extension method

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, lambda

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<MyItem> ListByName(string name)
    {
        IList<MyItem> myItems = new List<MyItem>();

        myItems.Add(new MyItem() { Name = "Item 1" });
        myItems.Add(new MyItem() { Name = "Item 2" });
        myItems.Add(new MyItem() { Name = "Item 3" });
        myItems.Add(new MyItem() { Name = "Item 3" });

        return (IList<MyItem>) myItems.Select(i => i.Name == name);
    }
}
```

I was getting a cast exception, initially (IEnumerable to IList) and an explicit cast does not work here.

My goal is to return an IList where the MyItem.Name property is equal to the method's argument.

Few questions here:

Should I be using "Select", "Where", or neither of those here?

What's the proper way to return my filtered IList here?

Comment: even intellisense can anwer your question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
return myItems.Where(i => i.Name == name).ToList();
```